# Swift Code for HTTP PUT

Tags: html, swift, rest

I have the following code that works perfectly with Python.

response = requests.put("http://localhost:5000/temp", data={'data':myData}).json()

I want to HTTP PUT data using an iOS application. However, I'm new at Swift and cannot get the right code to do the trick. I get error 400 (Bad Request).

Comment: Could you show us the code you have made so far. It makes it easier for us to help you :)

Comment: I have used different variations of the same code that Aron K. has posted below. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a framework like AlamoFire(https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to do such thing for you.

If you want to do it without frameworks you can do something like this:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: Url(string: "http://localhost:5000/temp"))
    request.HTTPMethod = "PUT"
    request.HTTPBody = "{'data':myData}"        
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
       (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) in
       //do something with the response
    }
    task.resume()
```

Be aware that you want to call an unsecured URL. By default Apple will not allow you to do this, but you can (if you're sure what you're doing) enable http-requests.

Comment: I guess it needs the data to be in JSON strictly

Answer (score 0):

request.HTTPBody = "{'data':myData}".data(using: .utf8)